# typecasting in android TextView

Tags: java, android

Why typecasting in this line works in android

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someId);
```

but in my case it leads to an error

```
public class B extends A{
   void b(){
     System.out.println("from B class");
             }}
public class A {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      B b =(B) new A();
       b.b();
 }}
```

if I'm not confused

```
findViewById(R.id.someId);
```

this string should return view object and view is a superclass towards textview. And so I can not understand why it is work in android. Please help me understand it would be very grateful for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the `findViewById` method is to return `View` but the actual object that is returned is not `View` but one of the classes that inherit from `View`, e.g. `TextView`. The object is already `TextView` so casting works correctly.

It is as if you had a method:

```
public A someMethod() {
    return new B();
}
```

and used it

```
B b = (B) someMethod();
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. Now I understood.

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someId);
```

This above cast is only valid if the view identified by `R.id.someId` is in fact a `TextView` (or any other view extending `TextView` - [and there are quite a few](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)). If it were, say, an `ImageView`, you'd get a `ClassCastException`.

Back to your code snippet:

```
public class B extends A { ... }
```

With the above definition every instance of `B` is also an instance of `A`. The opposite, however, is not true (and a common mistake): every instance of `A` is not necessarily an instance of `B`. This will become more clear as soon as you add another class that extends `A`:

```
public class C extends A { ... }
```

Objects of type `B` and `C` are instances of `A`, but `A` can be either `A`, `B` or `C`. And and instance of `B` can *never* be an instance of `C`. Therefore, the following is invalid:

```
B b = (B) new A();
```

You're creating a new instance of `A`, but `A` isn't an instance of `B`. Only the vice versa is true, as we established above. Hence the type cast is invalid. In fact, since you're creating a new `A`, it is always and only an instance of `A`, nothing more, nothing less.